# How to know Intel TSX is currently used by other process?

Tags: transactions, cpu, intel, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

Is there a way to know if a transaction is being processed using [Intel TSX](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/tsx-programming-considerations-ov.html) from another process/program?

Say, if I want to monitor the behavior of Intel TSX from an application. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSX transactions are very short, and don't have any sign that's visible to other CPUs.  It's basically all internal to the CPU core, with the effect being how / when / what it responds to MESI requests to share cache lines.  The timing effects are probably indistinguishable from ordinary contention.

Over a somewhat longer timescale, another process could use HW performance counter (e.g. via Linux `perf_event_open`) to track TSX activity, such as `rtm_retired.start` and `rtm_retired.commit` to count the number of transactions started and committed.  (There are similar events for HLE, but HLE unfortunately seems to be gone due to microcode updates and not even optionally enableable.)

Most of the perf events for TSX are about aborts and things that might cause aborts, since that's something you'd want to look for when profiling an application you already know uses TSX.

Comment: update: due to the TAA vulnerability (https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html), most Skylake-family CPUs have TSX disabled in microcode (no HLE, andRTM always aborting.) It seems the OS can set a bit to not advertize the now-useless "feature" in CPUID, but can't re-enabled RTM. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059422/processors.html . And the feature has been removed from Ice Lake. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_Synchronization_Extensions#History_and_bugs